# Is it bad practice to define a controller as a generic object instead of a function?

Tags: javascript

Just wondering, if you've got a controller that is a singleton (as in, you know there will only ever be one instance in your document), is there anything wrong with defining it as a generic object instead of a function? e.g.:

```
var SomeController = {
  initialize: function(userId){
    this.userId = userId;
  },

  alertUserId: function() { alert(this.userId) }
}

SomeController.initialize(999);
SomeController.alertUserId();
```

Comment: Cool thanks, I've just not really seen it around anywhere, which is why I was wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this. Infact, this object literal pattern has been around for a while now.

Further reading:

- http://christianheilmann.com/2006/02/16/show-love-to-the-object-literal/.
- http://rmurphey.com/blog/2009/10/15/using-objects-to-organize-your-code/.
- http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/

Comment: Thanks for the links to the articles. :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do that but You can also keep it more specific :

```
var myApp = myApp || {};


myApp.SomeController = myApp.SomeController || {};

myApp.SomeController = {

}


myApp.SomeController1 = myApp.SomeController1 || {};

myApp.SomeController1 = {

}
```

Here I am keeping all my `controllers` inside my application `myApp`. This is called nested namespace. The plus point here is less conflict among namespaces.

`var myApp = myApp || {};` will check for existing `myApp` if there is it will add to that else will create new and same with `myApp.SomeController = myApp.SomeController || {};` and `myApp.SomeController1 = myApp.SomeController1 || {};`

You should always maintain atleast one level nested namespaing in your app to avoid conflicts and keep your functionality more clear.

Comment: You might want to elaborate on what you are doing here. Why are you creating two objects Where the OP only needs one? What exactly is more "specific" here? How much of what you posted is relevant to the OP's question?

Comment: wtf is going on with this code?! just assign `myApp.SomeController = {}` once, no need to check if it already has a value with `myApp.SomeController || {}` if you're about to stomp over it anyway with the next line.

Comment: Have a look http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/829254/JavaScript-Namespace `Create Namespace If Not Exist` section